# Getting google-calendar event id is of size more than 200 character for few events. which I need <200 char?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have got calendar event for my accounts which contains unique ids for each event. For few events the id's are too large and my application needs id with size less than 200 character. But I am not sure why for few events the ids are too large? and not sure how to make it tiny without violating the uniqueness?

Answer (score 1):

You can use UUID, which is a 128-bit almost random number ( I say almost because in practice the likelihood to repeat it, it's close enough to zero). Basically, all programming languages have their library that generates UUID and the result would be something like:

***9d853330-21e1-415d-9237-9b80efb3b584***

Then you would need to use the array method `.split()` or its equivalent depending in the language you're using to get an array like this one:

```
['9d853330', '21e1',  '415d', '9237', '9b80efb3b584']
```

With that array, you could form a new string without the ***"-"*** due to it is not allowed as a valid id for your events as the [docs](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) say:

> Opaque identifier of the event. When creating new single or recurring
>   events, you can specify their IDs. Provided IDs must follow these
>   rules: characters allowed in the ID are those used in base32hex
>   encoding, i.e. lowercase letters a-v and digits 0-9, see section 3.1.2
>   in RFC2938 the length of the ID must be between 5 and 1024 characters
>   the ID must be unique per calendar Due to the globally distributed
>   nature of the system, we cannot guarantee that ID collisions will be
>   detected at event creation time. To minimize the risk of collisions we
>   recommend using an established UUID algorithm such as one described in
>   RFC4122. If you do not specify an ID, it will be automatically
>   generated by the server. Note that the icalUID and the id are not
>   identical and only one of them should be supplied at event creation
>   time. One difference in their semantics is that in recurring events,
>   all occurrences of one event have different ids while they all share
>   the same icalUIDs.

An example request body specifying the generated id would look like this:

```js
{
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2019-12-20T17:00:00-07:00",
    "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles"
  },
  "start": {
    "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles",
    "dateTime": "2019-12-19T09:00:00-07:00"
  },
  "id": "9d85333021e1415d92379b80efb3b584",
  "summary": "Id test"
}
```

Comment: I can see one more thing is we can generate md5hex for the string and then can use it as event I'd. But still I have doubt, why the id of event is coming as a very long string value in some cases while in other cases it is short string as shown in above example?

Comment: Due to the nature of the RFC2938 encoding algorithm, the word's length can vary. Programming languages UUID libraries give you a fixed word's length when you use them, that will solve your requirement  of having less than 200 char